# .Net 5 in Ubuntu cannot connect mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, networking

I have tested both Windows and Mac to connect to the remote database. Only Ubuntu deployed in Docker cannot connect
I don't know anything about the network layer.
Help

this is address
mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@cluster0.xxxxx.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

this is log

```
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00.koby6.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00.koby6.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.

---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain

at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)

at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)

at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: So it works in Docker with a Windows host, and it works in Docker with a Mac host, but it doesn't work in Docker on an Ubuntu (Linux) host? That's a networking issue, not a code issue.

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear enough. It's fine on Windows and Mac hosts, but it's not working on Docker with Ubuntu deployment code. I also understand that it is a network issue. Maybe it's an SSL or domain issue. But I don't know how to set it up

Comment: Do you mean then that it doesn't work in Docker on those same machines?

Comment: Please share with us way how you start docker container and firewalld settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my own problem by calling

```
apt-get install -y wget
apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
```

The error no longer occurs